# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.util'

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api, autogpt

I'm a Mac user, and I'm using Python 3.12 in a virtual environment. I'm encountering a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to run my AutoGPT project. After executing "python -m autogpt," I receive the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.util'

I have already tried updating the openai package, I have run requirements.txt ind the docs folder and autogpt.sh run --help

I hope someone can assist me.

Comment: python -m pip install autogpt

Comment: Collecting autogpt
  Downloading autogpt-0.0.1.dev0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of autogpt to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from autogpt) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Comment: You need to update torch.

Comment: I tried ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Is it maybe because of python version 3.12?

Comment: Here is link. https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-download-install-auto-gpt-step-by-step/

Comment: Ty, I will try.

Comment: OIC. you on  Mac. Mac and Linux use this python3 -m pip install autogpt

Comment: Now AutoGPT starts but If. i type in a command, It gives an error message that says, "Error communicating with OpenAI." It also suggests that I haven't saved my API key in the .env file, even though I've already done that. It's asking me to enter my OpenAI API key

Comment: I know you're using Mac.  But, I am not availabe right now.

Comment: Ok, After installing the openai package, I'm again encountering the error from openai.util import logger as openai_logger ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.util' and AutoGPT is not starting again..

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue with the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.util' it has been resolved by using a lower version of openai.

As for the specific openai versions to install to avoid the error, you can consider either openai==0.27.10 or openai==0.27.0, which should work without encountering the APIConnectionError.

AutoGPT starts now, but If I type in a command it crashes with this error: raise error.APIConnectionError("Error communicating with OpenAI") from e openai.error.APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI

Can someone assist me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.